# How to `update_all` based on a subquery in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, bulkupdate

I'm trying to achieve something pretty simple in PostgreSQL the Rails way.

Say you have a `User` model with 3 columns `id`, `cached_segment`, `cached_step`.
Say you already have a complex query that calculates `segment` and `query` on the fly, encapsulated in a scope `User.decorate_with_segment_and_step`. This returns an `ActiveRecord` relation, same as `User`, but with 3 additional columns:

```
id  cached_segment cached_step segment    step    cache_invalid
1   NULL           NULL        segment_1  step_1  TRUE
2   segment_1      step_2      segment_1  step_2  FALSE
3   ...
```

The SQL I would like to generate is the following (PostgreSQL flavor):

```
UPDATE users
SET cached_segment = segment_1
    cached_step    = step
FROM (#{User.decorate_with_segment_and_step.to_sql}) decorated_users
WHERE decorated_users.cache_invalid AND decorated_users.id = users.id
```

Ideally, I would be able to do something like

```
User.
  from(User.decorate_with_segment_and_step, 'decorated_users').
  where(cache_invalid: true).
  update_all('cached_segment = segment, cached_step = step')
```

I had no luck with the statement above, `update_all`, according the source code, simply discards the `from` clause when building the update statement.

Note: I am aware I could just use `User.connection.execute(my_raw_sql_here)`, which is what I'm doing right now. The goal is to stick with ActiveRecord.

Comment: ActiveRecord has its limits, which is good because doing complex SQL stuff using another layer of complexity (ActiveRecord or Arel tables) is not helping...

Comment: Have you tried `User.decorate_with_segment_and_step.where(cache_invalid: true).update_all('cached_segment = segment, cached_step = step')`?

Comment: Yes, sadly it seems only actual DB columns can be used in the update clause

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AR has its limits, but this isn't one of them. Assuming you're using Postgres for everything -- development, testing and production -- your incantation to do this is:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE users SET cached_segment = segment_1, cached_step = step FROM (#{User.decorate_with_segment_and_step.to_sql}) decorated_users WHERE decorated_users.cache_invalid AND decorated_users.id = users.id")
```

Hope it helps...